# Prevent repeat purchases of a product variation using WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've setup a WooCommerce variable product with a 'Free Trial' and 'Single Payment' option. I want to stop repeat purchases of the trial product for obvious reasons.

The following example shows how this can be done: https://gist.github.com/bekarice/0143d1b423857b0c6885

This example works as described with a products ID (which is set with the following variables):

```
$non_purchasable = 356;
$no_repeats_id = 356;
```

Unfortunately the code seemingly doesn't work when the above variables are set to the specific products 'free trial' variation ID.

Is there a way to modify the above example to work with a products specific variation ID?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting the correct variation ID? I've included an image below for reference:

[image: Image For Reference]

Comment: Yes, I used the correct one. I did check in the back office per your picture.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who gets stuck, please ensure that your past order history (for the user placing the order) is deleted. Once I deleted my order hostory this code started working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress-Woocommerce plugin to prevent repeated purchase. Mostly useful for downloadable products.

The following plugin is do the same thing. 
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-disable-repeat-purchase/22249871